# Unique bean of type - Exception

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

Below is my spring configuration.

```
<bean id="taskThreadExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor">
            <property name="concurrentExecutor" ref="threadPoolExecutor" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="threadPoolExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="300" />
        </bean> 

        <bean id="concurrentTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor" scope="prototype">
            <qualifier value="rmsTaskExecutor"></qualifier> 
            <property name="concurrentExecutor">        
                <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
                    <property name="corePoolSize" value="400" />
                    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="600" />
                    <property name="queueCapacity" value="3000" />
                </bean>     
            </property>
        </bean>
```

In my class i do wiring as follows

```
 @Autowired
 @qualifier("rmsTaskExecutor")
 private ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor;
```

At runtime., I get the following exception., saying No unique bean of type.

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type
>   [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   [taskThreadExecutor, concurrentTaskExecutor]

Dunnow where and what i missed., I am using spring 3.0.x version

Comment: Please add a question in your question, otherwise it's a bad question.

Comment: Exception is telling you what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I had corrected format., Yes you are right  I have two   "ConcurrentTaskExecutor" type  I tried byType, byName, Qualifier,  @resource  also.   Still I get same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is normal, you have 2 ConcurrentTaskExecutor (taskThreadExecutor and concurrentTaskExecutor) so try to use @Resource(..)